# Java - repetition in variable declarations

Tags: java, android

I'm not sure what this is even called, so it has been very difficult to search for an answer.

I am currently learning Java and Android development and have noticed a pattern where the type of object or variable being declared is repeated multiple times and I don't understand why.

For example:

```
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

Why does it have to be declared a type of EditText both before and after the assignment operator '='? Why isn't once enough? Why is this necessary?

I come from a ruby background and am having trouble wrapping my head around this.

Comment: It's called a [cast](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Comment: java is indeed very verbose when it comes to typing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a result of something called [Type Casting](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/12/what-is-type-casting-in-java-class-interface-example.html)

`EditText` inherits from type `View`.

Since you want a variable of type `EditText`, but `findViewById` returns an object of type `View`, 
you have to cast the result of `findViewById`  to `EditText`

To illustrate:

```
View uncasted = findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
EditText casted = (EditText)uncasted;
                  //casting happening on right side above
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code.

```
1883    public View findViewById(int id) {
1884        return getWindow().findViewById(id);
1885    }
1886
```

The return type is `View`. Since its a `EditText` object you cast it to `EditText`.

```
 EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
 // this (EditText) is explicit casting
```

Answer (score 1):

The `findViewById(...)` is a method which will return a `View` Object (in your case a view called edit_message). Java however sees that you want an `EditText` Object on the one side

```
 EditText editText = ...
```

and that a `View` is returned on the other side

```
... = findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

Java can't be sure that `EditText` is compatible with `View` (But you know that EditText is compatible with View because `EditText` is a child of the class `View`).

so to convince Java that your "edit_message" is actually an `EditText` Object, you have to **cast it explicitly** by adding `(EditText)` before the returning method `findViewById(R.id.edit_message);`

Afterwards your variable `editText` is a full blown `EditText` Object even when it came from a `View`.